# MongoDB C# driver - Change Id serialization for inherited class

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have implemented Repository pattern with a base entity class for my collections. Till now all collections had `_id` of `ObjectId` type. In the code, I needed to represent the `Id` as a string.

Here is how the `EntityBase` class look like

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EntityBase>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapIdProperty(x => x.Id).SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetSerializer(new StringSerializer().WithRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId));
});
```

Now I have a Language collection which Id will be plain string something like `en-GB`.

```
{
   "_id" : "en-GB",
   "Term1" : "Translation 1",
   "Term2" : "Translation 2"
}
```

`Language` class is inheriting the `EntityBase` class

```
public class Language : EntityBase
{
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
    public override string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The question is can I somehow change how the `Id` is serialized only for the `Language` class?

I don't want to change the behaviour of `EntityBase` class since I have a lot of other collections inheriting the `EntityBase`.

### Update

Here is what I tried and got exception. Not sure if what I have tried is possible.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Language>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapExtraElementsMember(c => c.Terms);
    cm.MapIdProperty(x => x.Id).SetIdGenerator(StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance);
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetSerializer(new StringSerializer().WithRepresentation(BsonType.String));
});
```

Here is the exception that I was getting:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The memberInfo argument must be for class Language, but was for class EntityBase.

at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.EnsureMemberInfoIsForThisClass(MemberInfo memberInfo)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.MapMember(MemberInfo memberInfo)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1.MapMember[TMember](Expression`1 memberLambda)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1.MapProperty[TMember](Expression`1 propertyLambda)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1.MapIdProperty[TMember](Expression`1 propertyLambda)
at Test.Utilities.MongoDbClassConfig.<>c.<Configure>b__0_1(BsonClassMap`1 cm) in F:\Development\Test\Utilities\MongoDbClassConfig.cs:line 23
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1..ctor(Action`1 classMapInitializer)
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap[TClass](Action`1 classMapInitializer)
at Test.Utilities.MongoDbClassConfig.Configure() in F:\Development\Test\Utilities\MongoDbClassConfig.cs:line 20
at Test.Portal.BackEnd.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in F:\Development\Test\Startup.cs:line 43
```

Comment: Maybe it is a naive approach. But could you implement the Id property again in your language class (overwrite the property of the base class). And then just add a specific mapping for this language class and handle the serialisation in the way you like?

Comment: That was the first thing that I have tried. I was getting an exception that Id is belonging to the class `EntityBase`.

Comment: Can't you make the Id-property `virtual` and use a generic type-parameter for the type of the `Id`. Then override it in your derived class? --- And also, you need to use the `[BsonId]`-attribute, to get it to recognize the `Id` as the BSON-id. Your `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` will not be inherited when you override your virtual property.

Answer (score 7):

I may be late with an answer, but I had the same problem, found this question, but no real answer how to solve and why is it happening.

What is happening is that Mongo driver doesn't explicitly understand polymorphism, and you must manually mention every type. All the types that inherit from the same class must be listed and explained to `BsonClassMap`.

In your case when you define your EntityBase you can list all the children that will be serialized and it would get it working. So something along the lines of:

```
[BsonDiscriminator(RootClass = true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Language), typeof(OtherEntity))]
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    [BsonId]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
}
```

should work.
In my case, I wanted to have a generic Entity save method and my entities are not aware of the Mongo driver so I could not use attributes. I had my ID in the EntityBase, so here's a simple generic add method (just the relevant, but working part):

```
public async Task Add<T>(T item) where T : EntityBase, new()
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<EntityBase>(cm =>
    {
        cm.AutoMap();
        cm.MapIdMember(p => p.Id);
        cm.SetIsRootClass(true);
    });
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<T>();

    await Db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name).InsertOneAsync(item);
}
```

As you can see, I must map the base class with every entry. Then the object is properly serialized and saved in the database.

Comment: unfortunately this forces you to reference MongoDB in the domain layer, which is not ok

Answer (score 6):

When you use the attribute `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` you are telling the serializer, that even though this is a string — you want it represented by the [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) type. `"en-GB"` is not a valid [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) therefor, the serializer throws an exception.

Use the `[BsonId]`-attribute if you want to specify that your property named `Id` must be a unique identifier within your collection.

There is also an `ObjectId`-data type within the driver, which you can implement instead.

I would add a generic type-parameter to your `EntityBase`-class.

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TId>
{
    [BsonId]
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

You could also implement a `EntityBase`-class, without the generic type argument as such:

```
public abstract class EntityBase : EntityBase<ObjectId>
{
}
```

Then for your `Language`-class

```
public class Language : EntityBase<string>
{
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

The driver should not have any trouble serializing a string-representation of an `ObjectId` to an `ObjectId`; but i would try it first — just to make sure.

Comment: This looks all very promising we are going to try it! Thank you.

Comment: Give it a shot; tell me of the results! :)

Comment: Did you have any luck with the above @zoranpro @Matthias?

Comment: I am going to test it tomorrow

Comment: I implemented it, but did yet change fully my Web API controller and test it. At least it compiles and makes perfect sense to me. I will also test it then. But I will accept your answer in upfront. I will tell you then about the result. Btw: I looked at your GitHub repositories. You have interesting MongoDB projects.

Comment: Tell me how it goes. Even if my answer is not solving your problem entirely, it might at least point you in the right direction. :)
Thank you for the kind Words @Matthias, feel free to critique them. I'm still kind of new to MongoDB; and any type of critique is welcome! :)

Answer (score 4):

I have just spent a few hours on this problem and was stumped - but I now have the Solution!! The problem with Gurgen's answer is that `SuperBaseEntity.Id` is always null - since the Id Property is overriden. I have managed this:

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
  [BsonIgnore]
  public abstract string Id {get;set}
}
public class ClassWithStringId : Base
{
  [BsonElement("_id")]
  [BsonId]
  public override string Id {get;set;}
}
public classs ClassWIthOidId : Base
{
  [BsonElement("_id")]
  [BsonId]
  public override string Id {get;set;}
}
...
//Class Map where the magic happens
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Base>(o =>
{
  o.SetIsRootClass(true);
  o.AutoMap();
}
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ClassWithOidId>(o =>
{
  o.AutoMap();
  //o.SetDiscriminator("...")//you probably need this
  o.MapIdProperty("Id"); //!!!! This is the solution! You need to reference the Id Property via string instead of the normal Expression c => c.Id, the latter will lead to an exception: "MemberInfo was for Type Base but not for Type XYZ"
  o.IdMemberMap.SetSerializer(new StringSerializer().WithRepresentation(BsonType.YourFavoriteType));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution. For me it worked.
Set `BsonRepresentation` for every base class and ignore `Id` field from `SuperBaseEntity` like this and create for every ID type base class derived from `SuperBaseEntity`

```
public class SuperBaseEntity
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectIdBaseEntity : SuperBaseEntity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public new string Id
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
}

public class StringIdBaseEntity : SuperBaseEntity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public new string Id
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
}

public class Language : StringIdBaseEntity
{
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public IDictionary<string, object> Terms { get; set; }
}

public class AllOtherEntities : ObjectIdBaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have defined Id virtual and then used `new` modifier. Completely not clear why you did all this for what scenarios.

Comment: You are right, there is no need to make Id in SuperBaseEntity as virtual. I will modify answer, thanks.

Comment: The use of new keyword is also a smell of a bad design

Comment: Do you have another way? Let me know I will change answer.